# Is it possible to change the path of StaticSitesClient.exe used by the SWA CLI?

Tags: swa-cli

By default, the SWA CLI downloads and tries to run a dependency called StaticSitesClient.exe to os.homedir()/.swa/deploy. Is it possible to specify a different directory? In our environment this path is blocked by AppLocker.